# AngularFire $save() not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've seen other posts about problems with $save(), but I couldn't relate it to my code. I have a profile controller with an updateProfile() method that ultimately attempts to save the new data to the database after it has been changed.

I have defined my profile controller as follows:

```
angular.module('angularfireSlackApp')
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($state, md5, profile) {
 var profileCtrl = this;
 var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 profileCtrl.profile = profile;

// Retrieves the user's email from input field, hashes it, and saves the data to the database
profileCtrl.updateProfile = function() {
console.log(profileCtrl.profile); // Profile object exists and is populated as expected
profileCtrl.profile.emailHash = md5.createHash(currentUser.email);
profileCtrl.profile.$save();
}
});
```

My user service:

```
angular.module('angularfireSlackApp')
// Provides a means of retrieving User data or list of all Users
.factory('Users', function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
// Provides a means of retrieving User data or list of all Users
 // Create a reference to users that can be used to retrieve an array of users
 var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
 users = $firebaseArray(usersRef);


 var Users = {
   // Returns a firebase object of a specific user's profile
   getProfile: function(uid) {
     return $firebaseObject(usersRef.child(uid));
   },
   // Returns the display name of a specific user
   getDisplayName: function(uid) {
     return users.$getRecord(uid).displayName;
   },
   // Returns the Gravatar url that corresponds to the user
   getGravatar: function(uid) {
     return 'www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + users.$getRecord(uid).emailHash;
   },
   // Returns a firebase array of users
   all: users
 };

 return Users;
});
```

Profile state from main app:

```
.state('profile', {
      url: '/profile',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl as profileCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'users/profile.html',
      resolve: {
        auth: function($state) {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user == null) {
              $state.go('home');
              console.log("In auth but user NOT valid");
            } else {
              console.log("In auth and user valid");
            }
          });
        },
        profile: function(Users) {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user != null) {
              console.log("In profile and user valid");
              return Users.getProfile(user.uid).$loaded();
            } else {
              console.log("In profile but user NOT valid");
            }
          });
        }
      }
  });
```

console.log:

[image: debug]

For some reason I'm getting an error that profileCtrl.profile.$save() is not a function. I know that the profileCtrl.profile object is legitimate and that I'm using $save() appropriately, but I just can't figure out what else could be the problem.

My gut feeling is that I'm missing something simple, but I'm brand new to AngularJS and Firebase so I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: You can call `$save` only on a `firebaseObject` or on a `FirebaseArray`, is your `profileCtrl.profile` anyone of them. Read more at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-save

Comment: I added some code to give a better idea of what's going on.
'profile' is a dependency that is part of a resolve method that returns a firebaseObject via the user controller. I did some debugging, and as far as I can tell it is a firebaseObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `resolve` of your "profile" state you are not returning anything.

You should fix it to:

```
auth: function($state, $firebaseAuth) {
  return $firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged().then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      $state.go('home');
      console.log("In auth but user NOT valid");
    } else {
      console.log("In auth and user valid");
    }
  }); // classic situation to use $requiresAuth() 
},
profile: function(Users, $firebaseAuth) {
  return $firebaseAuth().$requireSignIn();
}
```

Moreover, your service shouldn't keep the reference to the `$firebaseArray` but create it for each controller that wants to use it.

The down-side is you'll have to make some changes, but the up-side is a more predictable, maintainable code:

```
    var Users = {
    // Returns a firebase object of a specific user's profile
    getProfile: function(uid) {
        return $firebaseObject(usersRef.child(uid));
    },
    // Returns the display name of a specific user
    getDisplayName: function(uid) {
        // This is actually an issue to get the name synchronously, but I see no reason why not using the Firebase SDK and fetch a-sync
        //return users.$getRecord(uid).displayName;
        return usersRef.child(uid)
            .child('displayName')
            .once('value')
            .then(function (snap) {
                return snap.val();
            });
    },
    // Returns the Gravatar url that corresponds to the user
    getGravatar: function(uid) {
        // Again fetch a-synchronously
        //return 'www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + users.$getRecord(uid).emailHash;
        return usersRef.child(uid)
            .child('emailHash')
            .once('value')
            .then(function (snap) {
                return 'www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + snap.val();
            });
    },
    // Returns a firebase array of users
    all: function () {
        return $firebaseArray(usersRef);
    }
};
```

Also refer to the new AngularFire docs: [API reference](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md)

Comment: First, let's talk resolve method:

Check these out:
onAuthStateChange: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

$requireAuth: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-requireauth

onAuthStateChange doesn't return a promise like the depreciated $requireAuth(), which would've been used in this situation, so .then() wont' work. The 'profile' dependency only returns when a user is valid. 'auth' doesn't need to return anything since I can use firebase.auth().currentUser to retrieve the user.

Comment: P.S. This app is from an outdated AngularFire tutorial that I'm trying to update. So, maybe that's why things might not make sense. Also, code has been updated with an error log to give you a better idea of what is being returned.

Comment: You're using Firebase 3 SDK but gave a link to AngularFire 1 which only supports Firebase 2 SDK. From the link you add, the `onAuthStateChanged` returns a function, but it's for unsubscribing that's why it doesn't have `$save`

Comment: I have some mistakes in the code, I'll try and fix them later. In the meantime refer to https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md for reference

Comment: I know, I posted it so that you could see the difference as requireAuth might be used in this case and DOES return a promise. I figured you might have been thinking like that since you used .then(). Just forget the 'auth' dependency all together. It's actually not even needed. I got rid of the onAuthStateChanged in 'profile' and just retrieved the user using firebase.auth().currentUser and it seems to have worked. Given that I'm returning Users.getProfile(user.uid).$loaded(), why would onAuthStateChanged even matter?

Comment: Sometimes you need to respond to auth state changes. It gives users good experience. Currently you're getting current user synchronously so it leads to unexpected situations. If you'll return to `$requireAuth` you won't have to worry about it

Comment: $requireAuth is depreciated as far as I can tell. Like I said in my original post, I'm new to both AngularJS and Firebase so these things aren't apparent to me. Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `$requireSignIn()` https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#requiresignin make sure you're using the new AngularFire, the one which is compatible with Firebase 3

Comment: Ahh, now THAT is what I should have been using. I've refactored my code and everything seems to work now. You might have to elaborate a bit more on what is going on with the user service.

Comment: Do you mean why not use a `$firebaseArray` as an inner var? `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` are used for "3-way binding" and trigger and respond to `$digest` loops. You don't want that in services because they're not connected to any views, therefore they shouldn't have data bindings

Comment: I see. I'll have to check out the docs a little more to fully understand how it works. Fix the auth dependency in the first part of your answer and I'll accept it.